# convert simple VB script to MATLAB

Tags: matlab, excel, vba

I have some problem converting simples VB scripts (formating) into MATLAB:

VB script:

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Font.Italic = True
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
```

I tried:

```
xlswrite('test.xls',1,'A1');
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
Excel.Workbooks.Open('test.xls');

Range = Excel.Range('A1');
Range.Font.Italic = True; % Doesnt work
Range.Border.Item('xlEdgeRight').LineStyle = 1; % Doesnt work

Excel.Visible = 1;
```

Any workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably this line:

```
Range = Excel.Range('A1');
```

Your Excel object is an Application object, which doesn't have a Range property.  The VBA example you follow uses a (IMHO) poor practice of using the global default objects that are only available within the context of the application itself.  You need to grab a reference to the Workbook returned by this call:

```
Excel.Workbooks.Open('test.xls');
```

After that, you need to get the worksheet from it's indexed Worksheets property, *then* get the Range from that. Also, "xlEdgeRight" is an enumeration member so external calls have to use the integer values for them instead of a string.  You can replace xlEdgeRight with 10.

I know next to nothing about Matlab, but this is what the more explicit code would look like in VBA:

```
Dim book As Workbook, sheet As Worksheet, rng As Range

Set book = Application.Workbooks.Open("test.xls")
Set sheet = book.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set rng = sheet.Range("A1")
rng.Font.Italic = True
rng.Borders.Item(10).LineStyle = 1
```

You should be able to get it from there.